# foursquare venue result locale

Tags: json, http, foursquare

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning it says:

> You can specify the locale by setting the Accept-Language HTTP header in your request. Alternatively, you can add a locale=XXX parameter to your request but HTTP header specification is preferred. We currently support en (default), es, fr, de, it, ja, th, tr, ko, ru, pt, and id.

and

> If nothing is specified, for geographical entities (e.g., city names), we'll fall back to using the language that's most popular in the country for that venue.

Now, how do we get the locale of the API result? If I query with `tr` locale, it may answer me back with `en` or another fallback locale. I couldn't find it neither inside the results nor the response headers.

I need this to cache and show the users the right data. My website's fallback language is `en` for example, but the API might give me `de` for example.

Thanks.

---

**Edit** Here's an example of what I try to tell;

URL:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4adcda50f964a520354121e3
?client_id=[client_id]&client_secret=[client_secret]&v=20161115&locale=tr
```

Headers:

```
array (
   'Accept-Language' => 'tr',
   'Accept' => 'application/json'
)
```

Result (Cropped some unrelated items):

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "requestId": "582bfe9e1ed21964a18d3aab"
  },
  "response": {
    "venue": {
      "id": "4adcda50f964a520354121e3",
      "name": "La Pedrera (Casa Milà) (Casa Milà 'La Pedrera')",
      "contact": {
        "phone": "+34902202138",
        "formattedPhone": "+34 902 20 21 38",
        "twitter": "catfundacio",
        "facebook": "429182007214758",
        "facebookUsername": "lapedrera.barcelona",
        "facebookName": "La Pedrera-Casa Milà"
      },
      "location": {
        "address": "Pg. Gràcia, 92",
        "crossStreet": "Carrer Provença",
        "lat": 41.39509128050475,
        "lng": 2.1618343621091296,
        "postalCode": "08008",
        "cc": "ES",
        "city": "Barselona",
        "state": "Cataluña",
        "country": "İspanya",
        "formattedAddress": [
          "Pg. Gràcia, 92 (Carrer Provença)",
          "08008 Barselona Catalonia",
          "İspanya"
        ]
      },
      "canonicalUrl": "https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/la-pedrera-casa-mil%C3%A0\/4adcda50f964a520354121e3",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d12d941735",
          "name": "Anıt \/ Abide",
          "pluralName": "Anıtlar \/ Abideler",
          "shortName": "Abide",
          "icon": {
            "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/government_monument_",
            "suffix": ".png"
          },
          "primary": true
        },
        {
          "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d130941735",
          "name": "Bina",
          "pluralName": "Binalar",
          "shortName": "Bina",
          "icon": {
            "prefix": "https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/building\/default_",
            "suffix": ".png"
          }
        }
      ],      
      "description": "La Pedrera (Casa Milà) és un edifici construït per Antoni Gaudí i declarat Patrimoni de la Humanitat. Actualment és la seu de la Fundació Catalunya-La Pedrera.",
      "storeId": "",
      "tags": [
        "gallery",
        "gaudi",
        "modernisme",
        "museum",
        "photobooth",
        "sicted"
      ],
      "shortUrl": "http:\/\/4sq.com\/72NCMi",
      "timeZone": "Europe\/Madrid",
      "hours": {
        "status": "09:00'e kadar kapalı",
        "isOpen": false,
        "isLocalHoliday": false,
        "timeframes": [
          {
            "days": "Pzt\u2013Paz",
            "includesToday": true,
            "open": [
              {
                "renderedTime": "09:00\u201321:00"
              }
            ],
            "segments": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "attributes": {
        "groups": [
          {
            "type": "wifi",
            "name": "Kablosuz Bağlantı",
            "summary": "Ücretsiz Wi-Fi",
            "count": 1,
            "items": [
              {
                "displayName": "Kablosuz Bağlantı",
                "displayValue": "Ücretsiz"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "bestPhoto": {
        "id": "55672a92498ec352981dd144",
        "createdAt": 1432824466,
        "source": {
          "name": "Foursquare Web",
          "url": "https:\/\/foursquare.com"
        },
        "prefix": "https:\/\/irs2.4sqi.net\/img\/general\/",
        "suffix": "\/39082263_M0PK-NTv3A-0tI4j_aEIp5k6BEkliQTkMXS9TIPg_NQ.jpg",
        "width": 620,
        "height": 478,
        "visibility": "public"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `addresses, categories, some of the names, timeframes, attributes` sections are in fact **Turkish**, but the description and the most of the names are in fallback/local language which is **Spanish** in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locale is not specified in the API response.

If you don't specify anything in the `Accept-Language` HTTP header the response will default to the language that's most popular in the country. However, if you do specify a local the API won't fallback to anything else.

If your website's language is english, you can specify `en` in the `Accept-Language` HTTP header and the API will give you english too.

Comment: does it differ to use `http headers` and `locale` querystring variable when falling back to a location? I'm using the querystring method.

Comment: I've tried both types of locale setting together but it does return me the fallback locale for the place when it doesn't have a translation to that locale..

Comment: "HTTP header specification is preferred". Can you update your question with an example request where you're experiencing this behavior?

Comment: Ok I'll try to do it.